# closest value from all previous rows r

Tags: r, dataframe, distance, closest

I have a dataframe which I would like to add a column identifying the closest value to the respective column from only all previous values ignoring itself.

I found a closest value function but am unsure how to limit it to only previous rows. In the following example I would like to find the closest Revenue value considering only previous rows.

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(id=c(1:20),Revenue=sample(20))

closest<-function(xv,sv){
  xv[which(abs(xv-sv)==min(abs(xv-sv)))] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below using `dist` + `apply`

```
transform(
  df,
  close_prev = Revenue[apply(`diag<-`(m <- as.matrix(dist(Revenue)), Inf) / upper.tri(m), 2, which.min)]
)
```

which gives

```
   id Revenue close_prev
1   1       4          4
2   2       7          4
3   3       1          4
4   4       2          1
5   5      13          7
6   6      19         13
7   7      11         13
8   8      17         19
9   9      14         13
10 10       3          4
11 11      18         19
12 12       5          4
13 13       9          7
14 14      16         17
15 15       6          7
16 16      15         14
17 17      12         13
18 18      10         11
19 19      20         19
20 20       8          7
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Is there a way to identify the actual number? It looks like it's giving me the absolute value difference between respective cell and all previous closest value.

Answer (score 0):

To get only 1 closest value for each number you can change the function using `which.min` and use the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

closest <- function(xv,sv) xv[which.min(abs(xv-sv))]

df %>%
  mutate(close_prev = map_dbl(row_number(), 
           ~closest(Revenue[seq_len(max(.x - 1, 1))], Revenue[.x])))

#   id Revenue close_prev
#1   1       4          4
#2   2       7          4
#3   3       1          4
#4   4       2          1
#5   5      13          7
#6   6      19         13
#7   7      11         13
#8   8      17         19
#9   9      14         13
#10 10       3          4
#11 11      18         19
#12 12       5          4
#13 13       9          7
#14 14      16         17
#15 15       6          7
#16 16      15         14
#17 17      12         13
#18 18      10         11
#19 19      20         19
#20 20       8          7
```

All the previous values (`.x - 1`) are passed everytime in `closest` function. `max(.x - 1, 1)` is used to handle the 1st row since there is no value before that.